# Breaking change in std::tuple lexicographic comparison in C++20 with conversion operators?

Tags: c++, stl, c++20

Consider the following code, a simple Struct with all of the pre-C++20 comparison operators defined, as well as a conversion operator to `const char *` (that for this example throws, for simplicity of tracing).

```cpp
struct Struct
{
    int _i;
    Struct( int i ) : _i( i ) {}

    bool operator==( const Struct &b ) const { return _i == b._i; }
    bool operator!=( const Struct &b ) const { return _i != b._i; }
    bool operator<( const Struct &b ) const { return _i < b._i; }
    bool operator<=( const Struct &b ) const { return _i <= b._i; }
    bool operator>( const Struct &b ) const { return _i > b._i; }
    bool operator>=( const Struct &b ) const { return _i >= b._i; }

    operator const char *() const { throw "Crash"; return nullptr; }
};
```

Now let us put that structure into a `std::tuple`, just a single element for simplicity's sake. Create two of those and sort them (lexicographically, per `std::tuple`):

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <tuple>

int main()
{
    std::tuple<Struct> a( 1 ), b( 2 );

    printf( "%s\n", a < b ? "Right" : "Wrong" );
    return 0;
}
```

What does this output? Under C++17 it will print `"Right"` as you may expect. Under C++20, though, the same code will throw the exception in the `const char *` conversion operator.

Why? Because we haven't defined an `operator <=>` in our struct, and C++20's `std::tuple<Struct>` will end up calling `std::operator<=><Struct, Struct>` in order to determine whether `a < b` is true. Per the C++20 standard, `std::tuple` only defines the `operator ==` and `operator <=>` comparison operators, which the compiler then uses to perform the `<` operation.

What's surprising is `std::operator<=><Struct, Struct>` ends up being producing code equivalent to `(const char *) <=> (const char *)`. It ignores the `Struct` comparison operators that could have otherwise been used to synthesize `operator <=>`, in favor of the conversion operator.

In practice this means that our `std::tuple<Struct>` had a well-defined ordering in C++17 that now takes a different codepath through the `operator const char *` conversion, which results in different behavior at run-time.

My question:

Other than manually looking at all instantiations of `std::tuple` and verifying that either lexicographic comparisons are not performed, there are no conversion operators, or that any classes or structures contained within define `operator <=>`, is there a way to identify at compile-time that this problem exists in a large codebase?

Comment: In case this comes down to a compiler bug or quirk, can you add your compiler, its version, and any additional flags you're using?

Comment: Different example, but same topic overall https://stackoverflow.com/q/66497269/817643 - the answer also touches on `std::tuple` and its fallback behavior.

Comment: As far as the problem in larger code bases... I think some of the other critique in the other answer applies here too. You provide an *implicit* conversion. But your type isn't *really* implicitly replaceable by a pointer to a char buffer, is it? I think implicit conversion functions are so frowned upon because that is rarely true in general for most types.

Comment: @alterigel MSVC 16.11, Clang 12.0+ Tested in godbolt's compiler explorer on those two, no compiler flags other than specifying the STD.

Comment: @DanielJennings: This feels like a case where you've done something dubious. If a type is implicitly convertible, then one might reasonably expect that it is valid to compare the *converted* forms of the two objects. And in your case, it is not. So what does it mean that your type is it implicitly convertible to a `char const*`?

Answer (score 2):

> Other than manually looking at all instantiations of `std::tuple` and verifying that either lexicographic comparisons are not performed, there are no conversion operators, or that any classes or structures contained within define operator `<=>`, is there a way to identify at compile-time that this problem exists in a large codebase?

There, unfortunately, definitely isn't something you can do *within C++* to verify this in any way.

But at least you don't have to look at `std::tuple` (or `std::pair` or `std::vector` or ..., which behave the same) - you need to look for types, `T`, that:

- do not provide a `<=>` directly, and
- do provide a `<`, and
- provide a conversion function to some type `U`, where
- `U` does provide a `<=>`, and
- `U`'s `<=>` is a builtin.

This basically requires `U` to be a builtin type, because when we're evaluating `t1 <=> t2`, in order for `U(t1) <=> U(t2)` to be a candidate function, it needs to be either a builtin or an `operator<=>` candidate that is found by ADL  on `T` -- but in order for it to be a candidate it would need to be a non-member, non-template candidate. `operator<=>` should be a member function or, if not that, a hidden friend or, if not that, a non-member function template. None of those options would work.

This list seems like something that would be possible to write a clang-tidy check for. One difficulty would be that both `<=>` and `<` can be defined outside of the class. And also you have class templates to consider.

At least, the fix is easy once you run into the problem: provide a `<=>`. The following works in both C++17 and C++20:

```cpp
struct Struct
{
    int _i;
    Struct( int i ) : _i( i ) {}

    bool operator==( const Struct &b ) const { return _i == b._i; }
#ifdef __cpp_lib_three_way_comparison
    std::strong_ordering operator<=>( const Struct &b ) const { return _i <=> b._i; }
#else
    bool operator!=( const Struct &b ) const { return _i != b._i; }
    bool operator<( const Struct &b ) const { return _i < b._i; }
    bool operator<=( const Struct &b ) const { return _i <= b._i; }
    bool operator>( const Struct &b ) const { return _i > b._i; }
    bool operator>=( const Struct &b ) const { return _i >= b._i; }
#endif

    operator const char *() const { throw "Crash"; return nullptr; }
};
```

In this particular case, you could even default `operator<=>`, but in the general case that may not be true, so I'd rather write it out for the example.

Comment: A helper function that implements `<=>` in terms of `<` and `==` might be dangerous but useful here.