# Exactly which parts of the standard require this breaking change involving operator <?

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer, standards, c++20

A change was made in C++20, and I'm having a hard time finding where in the standard I can go look to learn that this change happened. Would someone please quote me the section of the standard that tells me this will happen?

I am aware of this question: [Breaking change in std::tuple lexicographic comparison in C++20 with conversion operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69489131/breaking-change-in-stdtuple-lexicographic-comparison-in-c20-with-conversion)

but it does not answer the question about where I can find this out in the standard.

With both gcc 11.2 and clang this code prints out `01` (the expected result) with `-std=c++17` and `10` with `-std=c++20`. Is this correct behavior? If it is, where in the standard should I look to find out why?

```
#include <iostream>

struct S {
    int a;

    S( int a ) : a( a ){ }

    operator
    int() const {
        return  a;
    }

    friend bool
    operator<( const S & lhs, const S & rhs ){
        return  lhs.a > rhs.a;
    }
};

int
main(){
    std::pair< int, S >  p1{ 0, 1 },  p2{ 0, 2 };
    std::cout <<  (p1 < p2)  <<  (p2 < p1)  << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: In C++20, `pair`'s `<` goes through `<=>` if possible -- and it is possible for `S`. It's just that `(s1 <=> s2) < 0` gives a different answer than `s1 < s2`.

Comment: There might be a better dupe target for this, not sure.

Comment: @Barry - I'm very specifically interested in the standard. Unless there is a dupe that mentions the places in the standard I can go look to learn this, I'm not getting an answer to my question.

Comment: @Barry - Thank you though for pointing me at that answer. It does help focus things a bit. Might it be a change to the documentation describing the standard library?

Comment: My clang 13.0.0 (a *brew* install) with `-std=c++20` printed out `01`.

Comment: @Eljay - I have a guess. Since this is a change to `::std::pair` and `::std::tuple` perhaps the available standard library isn't C++20 yet. Try it on compiler-explorer.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++17, [[pairs.spec]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/pairs.spec) defined all the relational operators. For instance, `operator<` was specified as:

> ```cpp
> template <class T1, class T2>
> constexpr bool operator<(const pair<T1, T2>& x, const pair<T1, T2>& y);
> ```
>
> *Returns*: `x.first < y.first || (!(y.first < x.first) && x.second < y.second)`.

In C++20, with the adoption of `<=>`, this looks a bit different. Also in [[pairs.spec]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/pairs.spec):

> ```cpp
> template<class T1, class T2>
>  constexpr common_comparison_category_t<synth-three-way-result<T1>,
>                                          synth-three-way-result<T2>>
>     operator<=>(const pair<T1, T2>& x, const pair<T1, T2>& y);
> ```
>
> *Effects*: Equivalent to:
>
> ```cpp
> if (auto c = synth-three-way(x.first, y.first); c != 0) return c;
> return synth-three-way(x.second, y.second);
> ```

Where `synth-three-way(x, y)` will do `x <=> y` if possible, otherwise do `x < y` and then `y < x` (see [[expos.only.func]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/library#expos.only.func-2)).

The issue here is that `x <=> y` for your type is actually valid, but does something different from `x < y`, so you get a different result.

Comment: Why is `x <=> y` valid? The `operator int()`?

Comment: @NathanPierson Yes. As per usual with conversion functions.

Comment: @konsolas That's how conversion functions in C++ have always worked. [Since C++98](https://godbolt.org/z/44cK73rac). That's basically the point of writing conversion functions - to opt into the functionality that the other type provides.