# Why does pair's comparison operator prefers conversion over user-provided operator<?

Tags: c++, c++20, comparison-operators

After switching to C++20 I found that some of our tests failed.
The output of the following code is different between C++17 and C++20 modes:

https://godbolt.org/z/hx4a98T13

```cpp
class MyString
{
public:
    operator char const *() const
    {
        std::printf("convert ");
        return nullptr;
    }

    bool operator<(MyString const & other) const
    {
        std::printf("MyString::operator< ");
        return 1;
    }
};

int main()
{
    MyString s1;
    MyString s2;
    std::printf("s1 < s2 = %d\n", s1 < s2);

    std::pair<MyString, MyString> pair1;
    std::pair<MyString, MyString> pair2;
    std::printf("pair1 < pair2 = %d\n", pair1 < pair2);
}
```

```
/// C++17
MyString::operator< s1 < s2 = 1
MyString::operator< pair1 < pair2 = 1
/// C++20
MyString::operator< s1 < s2 = 1
convert convert convert convert pair1 < pair2 = 0
```

It seems that `std::pair::operator<=>` prefers synthesized `operator<` over user-provided. Why is that so?

PS: I do know that making conversion operator explicit solves the issue, but I would really like to know what causes this behavior.

Comment: Comparison operators shouldn't be member functions. If you define <, define >, <=, and >= too.

Comment: Space ship calls spaceship on pair members. You'll need space ship in your class or define all comparison operators.

Comment: @273K the same behavior can be observed with hidden friends, too. The original code also had all other operators, I just omitted them for simplicity.

Comment: Kinda mostly dupe of this, I'd say. https://stackoverflow.com/a/66497568/817643

Comment: Is there a good reason that the converting operator is missing `explicit`?  Probably should be `explicit operator char const *() const`.  That being said, Drew's answer is spot on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a (presumably accidental) breaking change in C++20.

In C++20, ordering comparisons on `std::pair` use `operator<=>`, which in turn will use `operator<=>` **(if possible)** on its components.

The only available `operator<=>` on your `MyString` type is on the converted `char const *`, so that becomes the chosen comparison.

---

You can fix this by having `MyString` implement `operator<=>` instead of `operator<`.

**Or** you can make `operator char const *()` `explicit`, which will provide no `operator<=>`, causing the the three-way comparison to be [synthesized from your `operator<`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/standard_library/synth-three-way).

Comment: It's only "breaking" because that type was already broken. You could write `s1 > s2`  (the reverse comparison!) in C++17, which means the type actually already had *all* comparison. C++20 just calls the user code out on such stuff.